# SVG paint-order с интервалом между буквами в Chrome

Tags: css, svg, google-chrome, firefox

В SVG атрибут `paint-order` позволяет нам управлять последовательностью, в котором отрисовываются заливка и обводка текстового содержимого и фигур, и очень полезно помещать обводку поверх заливки.

Однако, я только что обнаружил, что в Chrome при изменении свойства CSS `letter-spacing` вместо того, чтобы рисовать все `strokes` поверх всех заливок, кажется, что каждая буква окрашивается индивидуально.

Например, учитывая этот фрагмент:

```css
text {
  font-size: 60px;
  stroke: wheat;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
  paint-order: stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="120">
  <text x="10" y="100">This is an example</text>
</svg>
```

Вот так выглядит в Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В то время как,  в Firefox результат именно такой, как я ожидал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, прежде чем сообщать об ошибке, я хотел бы спросить: действительно ли это поведение зависит от реализации (то есть каждый браузер реализует его так, как им нравится), или это указано где-то в документации SVG?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG paint-order with letter-spacing in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64949681/7394871) от участника  [@Megaptera novaeangliae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12273078/megaptera-novaeangliae)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64949681/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Это альтернативное решение: вместо добавления цвета к обводке текста `stroke ="wheat"`,   вы можете использовать фильтр `feMorphology` с оператором = "dilate".

```css
text {
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="120">
<filter id="outline">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded"
operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
<feFlood flood-color="wheat" result="color" />
<feComposite in ="color" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
  <text filter="url(#outline)" x="10" y="100">This is an example</text>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64951574/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>